# Ancora para outra página com scroll para o conteúdo

Tags: javascript, front-end

Tenho um link em uma página que vai me mandar para outra página, mas eu preciso que quando a página solicitada for carregada, faça um `scroll` para o conteúdo que eu quero focar.

Se fosse na mesma página, não teria problema porque já faço isso em determinado momento, mas como são em páginas separadas, não tenho noção de como fazer isso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scroll em uma mesma página basta colocar o ID do elemento no `href`:

```
<a href="#id-do-elemento">Go</a>
```

Para realizar em outra página o mecanismo é mesmo, basta adicionar o ID no fim da URL:

```
<a href="outra-pagina.html#id-do-elemento">Outra Página Go</a>
```

Comment: Deu certo! E como eu faria a animação do scroll nesse caso? Porque nesse método, já cai "seco" na section, gostaria de fazer uma animação.

Comment: Isso "não" é possível nativamente @Tamiris, mas tem algumas soluções alternativas como [essa](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3503621/3497987), [essa](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3659116/3497987) e [essa](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14185983/3497987). Também tem outras soluções usando linguagem do servidor...

Answer (score 5):

O processo é quase o mesmo e bem simples, é só colocar o `nome_da_pagina#nome_da_ancora`:

```
<a href="contato.html#maps">Nos encontre no mapa</a>
```

Mas se você faz esse redirecionamento por javascript (pela tag da sua pergunta, é o que dá a entender), use:

```
location.href = 'contato.html#maps';
```

Comment: O que é "nome_da_ancora"?